# How to use DNS for App Services within an Azure VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-app-services, azure-dns

I've seen guides on how to deploy a DNS within a VNET for use with VM's, but I can't figure out how to do this for App Services. Especially since App Services don't have a static internal IP (at least not one that I can find in the portal).

#### Local environment

This is how my applications run on my local machine using docker-compose:

[image: Docker bridge network]

#### Production environment

In production, these applications are running as App Services (webapps for containers) inside a vnet.

In order to get the network traffic working, I thought I'd deploy an application gateway with a multi-site listener, and then add DNS records to point the "cat" and "dog" hostnames to the app gateway. But I can't find any guides on how to create DNS zone records for the app gateway, nor how to make the frontend AppService use that DNS for traffic within the vnet.

[image]

Maybe I should stop to ask, is this even the easiest approach? All I want is to let the frontend App Service be able to communicate with the backend services within thr VNET using simple hostnames.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the app gateway exposed on the internet and accessible directly or it's the front end that calls it (as a proxy server)?

Comment: It's only accessible from within the VNET

Comment: Your App Service is not actually in the VNET unless it's hosted in an ASE (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro).

Comment: That's incorrect. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet

Comment: True but according to the doc : "This feature is still in preview". I wouldn't put any production system in there.